# Bootstrap Layout Column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I have problems to build layout with bootstrap css,

```
<style>
.item {
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #e2e3e4;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #e2e3e4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #e2e3e4;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.item img{
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#timeline {
    margin: 15px 0;
}
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            for ($i = 1; $i < 15; $i++) {
                if ($i % 7 == 1 || $i == 1) {
                    echo '<div id="timeline" class="col-md-8">';
                } else {
                    echo '<div id="timeline" class="col-md-4">';
                }
        ?>
                <div class="item">
                    <img class="lazy img-responsive" src="http://420placehold.it/art/300-300-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every multiples of 7 I use big images, but I have white space like this one http://i57.tinypic.com/x35pg2.png

Anybody can help me fix this ?? I need make layout like this with bootstrap http://codepen.io/nouveau/pen/Litmp

CLOSE :

Oh my mistake, sorry all i replace `if ($i % 7 == 1 || $i == 1)` to `if ($i % 6 == 1)` i misrepresented `nth-child(12n+1),nth-child(12n+7)` it's work fine now

Comment: What kind of layout do you want to achieve?

Comment: please mention layout.

Comment: You could use the exact code from that example and not bootstrap classes for that part of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options you can use for this.

First is to use a mosaic script such as http://desandro.github.io/masonry/ to make everything automatically arrange to fit.

The second would be to use column ordering (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) on the 8th and 9th then 22nd and 23rd columns etc. So using col-md-4 col-md-pull-8 and col-md-8 col-md-push-4. This may get more complicated if you introduce other sizes.